# Unix command to Gzip the files and move it to home directory

Tags: unix, command, gzip

Below Unix commands are used to get the list of last 30 minutes modified files which works perfectly.

```
touch -t 02231249.00 /tmp/last30min
find /mydirectory -type f -newer /tmp/last30min
rm /tmp/last30min
```

Can someone please provide me the commands to gzip those files and move it to home or tmp directory.

Thanks for your help!!!.

Comment: `gzip <file> && mv <file>.gz ~`

Answer (score 2):

Pipe the arguments of your find command separated with null characters (important if your filenames include whitespaces) to `xargs` to do the job

```
find /mydirectory -type f -newer /tmp/last30min -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'gzip "{}"; mv "{}".gz ~'
```

where `-I{}` tells `xargs` to replace every `{}` in the command with the input line, i.e. the current file found by `find`.

If your are using the Z shell (`zsh`), it's much more simper, everything can be done in a oneliner:

```
for i (/mydirectory/**/*(mm-30)) { gzip $i && mv $i.gz ~ }
```

Here `**` searches recursively, and `(mm-30)` means **m**odified in the last (-) 30 **m**inutes.

Answer (score 1):

Your touch command doesn't work correctly, I checked the time stamps and they are for, in my timezone the following date:

```
$ touch -t 02231249.00 /tmp/last30min
$ perl -e'print scalar localtime((stat("/tmp/last30min"))[9])'
Sat Feb 23 12:49:00 2013jamie@jamie-Ideapad-Z570:~/temp$
```

I think this command will do what you are asking for

```
for f in `find . -mmin -30 -print`;do echo $f;gzip -c $f > $HOME/$f.gz;done
```